# Does Allah also protect the Arabic language?

Tags: arabic

The Qur'an is protected by Allah:

> Indeed, it is We who sent down the Qur'an and indeed, We will be its guardian. -- [Qur'an 15:9](https://quran.com/15/9)

This does not say the Arabic language is also protected.  Consequently, it seems theoretical possible that, over time, the Arabic language could become extinct (see [List of Extinct Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_extinct_languages)), or evolve into a language that cannot be used to read the Qur'an.  In fact, I've heard that Qur'anic Arabic is already considerably different from day-to-day Arabic.

However, it seems odd to have a holy and protected book without the means to read and understand it.  This suggests that the Arabic language might also be protected.

**Question**: Does Allah also protect the Arabic language?

Comment: Hm... as today it feels like Latin (a written language that nobody speaks outside of newspapers, books, and tv or radio news) in the middle ages I'd say no!

Comment: how this question has no answer?